# ListView update in fragments android

Tags: android, listview

I have a code like this:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_left_panel, container,false);
        json = new JsonParser(getActivity(),new LeftFragment());
        json.execute(new String[] {json_url});

        return view;
    }

    public void test(List<ProjectList> projList){
        this.projList = projList;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReturnList(ProjectListAdapter results) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        listItems = (ListView) getView().findViewById(R.id.items);
        listItems.setAdapter(results);
    }
```

Everything is working.

The json is the asynctask on other class file that parses json coming from the web. `onReturnList(ProjectListAdapter results)` gets the data coming from the async task. The result is the adapter to be used for the ListView. All of that's working just fine, but I can't figure out how to udpate the list view because the async task only executes after the view has been returned (correct me if I'm wrong).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe passing the ListView to the constructor to the AsyncTask sub-class and update it on onPostExecute method?